# Rename some variable names and procedure names

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a huge Excel VBA project.

Currently I need to rename some variable names and procedure names.
But it contains tens of thousands of lines of code and many classes.
I use the "Find & Replace" function, but it's often confused.

[image]

Because my project has a lot of code.
Also, my project has some procedures with same name on Modules & Class Modules.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want to rename or rearrange? I personally find having `Find Whole Word Only` checked works well to rename variable and procedures.

Comment: If you are looking for some Visual Studio or Eclipse style Refactor / Rename functionality: No, there is no such thing in VBA.

Comment: @Raymond Wu: I know "Find Whole Word Only". But, even if those have the same name, some need to be renamed and some should not.

Comment: @MingShou Then I don't think you will have it any easier... limit the Find/Replace by procedure/module or if majority needs to change, change all of them then undo the minority..

Comment: You could profit from [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) allowing to organize folder groups and filter search items in a Code Explorer, at least to facilitate re-checks before renaming. @MingShou

Comment: Be careful with the Find & Replace cause you might end up with the famous *User-defined type not defined* error. Always work in a copy or keep a copy safe.